# Drupal 7: How can I link uploaded images (via an image field) to specific URLs contained in a text field?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to link individually uploaded images (via an image field) to different external URLs (e.g. Link one image in one post to a website outside of my own). I've found modules that allow me to link image fields to nodes within my drupal site, but nothing that allows me to link uploaded images individually to different urls. That said, I figured I could create a text field, input a URL there, and set my Image Field in views to be linked to the contents of that field. E.g. Destination: [field_link_image_to]

However that doesn't seem to be do-able either. Any suggestions as to how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Link field module (https://www.drupal.org/project/link). After enabling add this field to the same content which contains the image you want to link to specific URLs. 
Create a view then include both image field and link field url (you will get the exact URL which you will enter into the link field) then add custom text and create your html accordingly.

Let me know if it works or you want something else.
Thanks.